# como arreglar este stored procedure?

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, stored-procedure

estoy creando un stored donde, si el *pacienteId es mayor a 0* (para que lo modifique en un pacienteId existente) modifique su domicilio (update)...

```
alter PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_tweb_cambio_direccion_api]
@pacienteId numeric,
@calle varchar(30),
@altura varchar(10),
@piso varchar(10),
@departamento varchar(4)

AS

select COD_PACIENTE as pacienteId from TWEB_MM_LISTA_GENERAL where COD_TWEB = 31852 
If @pacienteId > 0
select * 
from MM_PACIENTE where COD_PACIENTE = 13391 

 
UPDATE MM_PACIENTE 
SET DOM_CALLE = '85',
DOM_NRO= '139',
DOM_PISO = '8',

    DOM_DPTO = 'B'
WHERE COD_PACIENTE = 13391

--sp_tweb_cambio_direccion_api 31852
```

Al stored lo llamo: sp_tweb_cambio_direccion_api

pero el error es el siguiente:

> El procedimiento o la función 'sp_tweb_cambio_direccion_api' esperaba el parámetro '@calle', que no se ha especificado.

Por lo que lei es algo sencillo de arreglar pero no veo como.

Desde ya mil gracias a todos!

PD: (intente colocar el stored en modo codigo para que se vea mejor y no pude).
Edito: entiendo que no loe paso los 4 parametros restantes (piso, calle, depto y numero), lo que no enteindo es donde colocarlo para que asi funcione.

Comment: Hola Luis, puedo notar que recibes 5 parámetros pero en el código solamente utilizas @pacienteId en un IF, todo lo demás siempre hace lo mismo porque no está parametrizado. ¿Será posible que describas con más detalles lo que quieres lograr? Tambien considero necesario que indiques cuándo se produce el error ¿será al guardar el SP? o ¿será al tratar de ejecutarlo? si fuera al tratar de ejecutarlo por favor incluye el código que estás utilizando.

Comment: Pablo gracias por tu pronta respuesta!
el error ocurre al momento de ejecutarlo, no hay codigo extra por que el error ocurre en el mismo SQL a modo de prueba (a lo cual nisiquiera puedo llevarlo a algun programa)..
Con respecto a lo que quiero hacer con este stored es, que al momento de ver que el pacienteId no es 0 (a lo cual entiende que existe uno) modificar los datos

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Usa el boton [edit] para modificar tu pregunta y agrega como estas llamando al SP... el error dice que no le estas pasando un parametro...

Answer (score 1):

No compares directamente a una consulta a la que le has puesto un alias:

Es vez de poner:

```
select COD_PACIENTE as pacienteId from TWEB_MM_LISTA_GENERAL where COD_TWEB = 31852
```

usar :

```
set @pacienteId = (select COD_PACIENTE from TWEB_MM_LISTA_GENERAL where COD_TWEB = 31852)
```

Si no necesitas pasar mas que el Id como parámetro a tu store puedes declararlos usando la palabra reservada del sql 'declare' (justo como lo tienes cuando configurar tu store)

Comment: Ahora, lo que no le veo utildad es para que haces una consulta general si tu Id es mayor a cero, no deberías hacer el update y luego la consulta select?, y si todo eso es un bloque debes usar si o si, BEGIN y END en tu IF

Answer (score 1):

Apartando el hecho de que el Stored Procedure actualizará al mismo paciente siempre, lo cual no produce resultados significativos, la respuesta concreta a tu pregunta es que el error ocurre porque no estás pasando valores a todos los parámetros.

Ten en cuenta que para poder ejecutar un Stored Procedure que requiere un conjunto de parámetros que no son opcionales, debes incluir un valor para cada parámetro.

Utiliza el siguiente ejemplo para ejecutarlo desde SQL

```
EXEC [dbo].[sp_tweb_cambio_direccion_api] 
     @pacienteId = 1, 
     @calle = '85', 
     @altura = 'ALT', 
     @piso = '8', 
     @departamento = 'B'
```

Ten en cuenta que aunque esto ejecuta el SP sin errores, los valores que pasas a cada parámetro no son utilizados.

Por favor incluye más detalles con ejemplos de uso y resultados esperados si quieres sugerencias para mejorar el SP en si.